# FIlling a zone with S9(5)V9(8) COMP-3

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I want to fill a file with this type of data.

```
01 FILE-LINE.
    05   VAR1   PIC S9(5)V9(8) COMP-3.
    05   VAR2   PIC S9(15)V99 COMP-3.
```

Can anyone help me to fill this lines
When i put All '0' on these fields and i test `IS NUMERIC`, it said that they are not numeric

Comment: Your title says COMP-3, but your micro snippet doesn't use COMP-3.  VAR1 and VAR2 are USAGE DISPLAY.  FILE-LINE is not NUMERIC.

Comment: you are right, i forgot the 'COMP-3'

Comment: Please show the statement where you "put All '0' on these fields".

Comment: Is this a homework question? Please post your code and the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `Initialize FILE-LINE`.

The rules for [INITIALIZE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=statements-initialize-statement) are a bit complicated, but flexibility begets complexity so there you are.

In this case, because you have numeric data items and they don't have VALUE clauses, INITIALIZE will do the equivalent of `Move Zeroes To VAR1` and `Move Zeroes To VAR2`.

Answer (score 0):

Because variables VAR1 and VAR2 are packed (COMP-3) and belongs to a group level, you can't move ZEROS to group level FILE-LINE. Instead, you must move ZEROS to VAR1 and VAR2, explicitly.

Moving ALL '0' to FILE-LINE results in
X'F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0'.

Moving ZEROS to VAR1 VAR2 results in
X'0000000000000C00000000000000000C'.

Comment: Yes you can, but depending on the actual code, which we haven't seen, you may not get the result you expected.